# Error "Failed to create the part's controls" with Scala 2.11 in Eclipse Neon 4.6?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, macos-sierra

I downloaded the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, [this](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/neon/3) and macOS version of this [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/neon3), to use it for Apache Spark course [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data/) requiring Scala 2.11 and older version of SBT. Unfortunately, the older Eclipse Neon version is causing an error with the older Scala IDE version 2.11:

> *Failed to create the part's controls.*

[image]

*.metadata/.log file*

```
!SESSION 2017-09-02 12:11:58.881 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/hhh/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/hhh/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2017-09-02 12:12:38.118
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata 1 0 2017-09-02 12:13:40.239
!MESSAGE No translation source unavailable. Default language will be used.
!SESSION 2017-09-02 12:20:46.970 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 12:20:47.510
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/HookConfigurator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hookregistry.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hookregistry.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookConfigurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2017-09-02 12:20:57.304
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-09-02 12:21:20.184
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/FrameworkProperties)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4032)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3708)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/framework/internal/core/FrameworkProperties
    at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.configuration.WeavingStateConfigurer.getConfigArea(WeavingStateConfigurer.java:393)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.configuration.WeavingStateConfigurer.currentConfigStateIsWeaving(WeavingStateConfigurer.java:400)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.configuration.WeavingStateConfigurer.changeWeavingState(WeavingStateConfigurer.java:92)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.diagnostic.StartupDiagnostics$.scala$tools$eclipse$diagnostic$StartupDiagnostics$$ensureWeavingIsEnabled(StartupDiagnostics.scala:67)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.diagnostic.StartupDiagnostics$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(StartupDiagnostics.scala:53)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ui.DisplayThread$$anon$1.run(DisplayThread.scala:10)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkProperties cannot be found by org.scala-ide.sdt.aspects_3.0.4.v-2_11-201407232043-c46f499
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 0 2017-09-02 12:23:13.724
!MESSAGE Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [helloworld$ [in [Working copy] helloworld.scala [in hello [in src [in hello]]]] does not exist]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-02 12:23:14.958
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to scala.tools.eclipse.InteractiveCompilationUnit
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaCompilationUnitEditor$class.getInteractiveCompilationUnit(ScalaCompilationUnitEditor.scala:84)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaSourceFileEditor.getInteractiveCompilationUnit(ScalaSourceFileEditor.scala:68)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaSourceFileEditor.createPartControl(ScalaSourceFileEditor.scala:297)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$1.run(NewElementWizard.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4032)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3708)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 2 2017-09-02 12:23:15.155
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor
    at scala.tools.eclipse.actions.ScalaCompilationUnitEditorActionContributor.setActiveEditor(ScalaCompilationUnitEditorActionContributor.scala:12)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBars.partChanged(EditorActionBars.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$18(WorkbenchPage.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$1.run(NewElementWizard.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4032)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3708)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-02 12:23:15.156
!MESSAGE An exception occurred while notifying part listeners
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ITextEditor
    at scala.tools.eclipse.actions.ScalaCompilationUnitEditorActionContributor.setActiveEditor(ScalaCompilationUnitEditorActionContributor.scala:12)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBars.partChanged(EditorActionBars.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$18(WorkbenchPage.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$1.run(NewElementWizard.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4032)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3708)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 0 2017-09-02 12:26:22.901
!MESSAGE Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [hellotest$ [in [Working copy] hellotest.scala [in hello [in src [in hello]]]] does not exist]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-02 12:26:23.272
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to scala.tools.eclipse.InteractiveCompilationUnit
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaCompilationUnitEditor$class.getInteractiveCompilationUnit(ScalaCompilationUnitEditor.scala:84)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaSourceFileEditor.getInteractiveCompilationUnit(ScalaSourceFileEditor.scala:68)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.ScalaSourceFileEditor.createPartControl(ScalaSourceFileEditor.scala:297)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
```

**How can I fix the error and get the Eclipse Neon 4.6 working with the older 2.11 Scala IDE Version?**

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message (this is a hidden directory so Finder won't normally show it).

Comment: @greg-449 I pasted the .log to the body and it was too long so I shared it [here](https://pastebin.com/A2VgeC8P) as well, thank you for the tip +1. I found `!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable`, `!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 0 2017-09-02 12:23:13.724
!MESSAGE Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [helloworld$ [in [Working copy] helloworld.scala [in hello [in src [in hello]]]] does not exist]
`

Answer (score 1):

This code is using class `org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookConfigurator` which does not exist in recent versions of Eclipse. Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) was the last release to have this class. You will not get this code to work on a later release.

Comment: This old Eclipse does not even open on my macOS Sierra, all the time coming the error msg `Eclipse crashed unexpectedly` where I cannot see any GUI of Eclipse. I tried Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 64bits this [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz&mirror_id=17).

Answer (score 0):

I got things working by using the old Scala IDE versions from [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170302090237/http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html) and the old download links still seem to work

- [here](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/4.5.0-vfinal-neon-211-20161213/scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64.zip) for Win32
- [here](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/4.5.0-vfinal-neon-211-20161213/scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-macosx.cocoa.x86_64.zip) for macOS
- [here](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/4.5.0-vfinal-neon-211-20161213/scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz) for Linux

and as of the writing day, I got the Scale IDE version 2.11 running.